# Is my GPU working?

Tags: drivers, ati, gpu

If I boot to Ubuntu and `lspci` shows drivers for my GPU, does this mean it's working? I have tested performance using Globs and my scores averaged around 58 FPS.

I'm having issues getting it to be detected in Windows and was assuming it to be dead.

Running something like a 5660 on a Sony Vaio e series.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So Ubuntu was correct with the GPU working! I updated the windows install and it is now working there too.

Answer (score 0):

`lspci` with no option doesn't show drivers. It only shows detected devices. If your device turns up, it means that it's plugged in and not completely dead, but it doesn't imply that the device is working correctly.

If `lspci -k` or `lspci -v` reports that your device is in use by a driver, that usually implies that the driver was able to complete some form of initialization. It gives you more confidence that the device is working, but again not complete confidence. Buggy hardware (in the sense that this particular piece of hardware is malfunctioning, as opposed to a design issue) is fairly rare, but not impossible.

Comment: OK thanks! Both commands have 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller replies that contain the correct driver, which means that there is a higher chance that this card is actually working?

Do you perform any GPU benchmarks? I attempted to use Phoronix but was unable to get it going, and have been unable to find anything to compare my Globs results to.