# Is my GPU working correctly?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel

Nvidia GeForce 525M. **How can I test whether my GPU is actually working as a GPU, and it's not my integrated graphics/CPU filling in?** My CPU load seems unusually high.

Instead of [actual driver verification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331247/is-my-gpu-working), I'd just like to see some cool 3D stuff that doesn't kill my CPU.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if Ubuntu is using my NVIDIA graphics card?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a set of utilities, and an information string which provide what you are looking for.  They need to be installed... Open a terminal window <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

Install the utilities

`sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

The command `glxinfo | more` will contain information about how the graphics section looks up.  Try `glxinfo | grep string` - you are *not* looking for llvmpipe!

A simple test graphics program is `glxgears`, which will tell you how many frames per second are being generated.